# Deleting very large no of files from hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have 4 million files in my single node hadoop cluster HDFS on Cento 7.2. Due to some corruption from my application, hundreds of thousands of duplicate files got stored in HDFS. I want to delete these files from hdfs.

I tried doing it using a shell script but it is taking a lot of time (100k files in 2 days). Script contained single command( `hdfs dfs -rm --skipTrash <file path>`)

Comment: Why not delete the directory, if you can.

Comment: The directory contains valid file also. so deleting directory is not an option.

Comment: Does the filename contain any kind of pattern ?
I mean can you segregate the bad files with the useful files with filename , then deleting files with certain pattern can make a difference.

Comment: I have the list of filenames to delete. but that is huge(20 lakhs). The main problem is `hdfs dfs -rm <filename>` is taking a lot of time. Is there any other way to delete these files?

Comment: If list of valid files is small, then move them to different directory and then delete the directory. Post that move back valid files to original directory.

Comment: How do you generate the list of invalid files. You can run delete command in parallel as well.

Comment: Why not pass all the files as argument to a single `hdfs dfs -rm` command? Running them individually is opening and closing client connections to Namenode and is taking more time.

Comment: @Ambrish I have a files with list of all the invalid file path in hdfs. How to delete multiple files parallely?

Comment: @franklinsijo passing all the files as argument throwing error `Argument list too long`.

Comment: That is the limitation by bash. `getconf ARG_MAX` should give you the max number of arguments you can pass to the command. Modify the command as per this value.

Comment: Passing all the filepaths in single command and increasing arg_max solved the problem. Also need to increase  hadoop_client_heap size

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
hdfs dfs -find <path> | xargs -P 10 -n 1000 hdfs dfs -rm -skipTrash
```